# Java 8 CompletableFuture - fan out implementation

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, promise

I was wondering what is the best way to implement a fan out type of functionality with Java 8 Completable future. I recently rewrote a function that had a bunch of old `Future` instances and then calling get in a loop, blocking on each one, to a somewhat cleaner variant using `CompletableFuture`. However I am seeing about 2x drop in performance so I am assuming something is not quite right in the way I'm using the new API. The code looks something like this:

```
if (!clinet.login()) {
        throw new LoginException("There was a login error");
    }
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> smths = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(client::getSmth);

    CompletableFuture<List<Data>> smths2 = smths.thenApply(client::getInformation)
            .thenApplyAsync((list) -> list.stream().map(obj -> mapper.map(obj, Data.class)).collect(toList()));

    List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, AnotherData>>> waitGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getIvPercentileM12M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getIvPercentileM6M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getIvPercentile2M6M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getIvPercentile2M12M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getIvPercentile2M24M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getHvPercentileM6M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getHvPercentile2M6M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getHvPercentileM12M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getHvPercentile2M12M));
    waitGroup.add(notablesFuture.thenComposeAsync(clientb::getHvPercentile2M24M));

    CompletableFuture
            .allOf(waitGroup.toArray(new CompletableFuture[waitGroup.size()]));

    List<Data> data = smths2.join();
    Map<String, Set<AnotherData>> volPercent = waitGroup.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .flatMap((e) -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                            toSet())));

    data.forEach((d) -> {
        Set<AnotherData> asdasd = volPercent.get(d.getSymbol());
        if (asdasd != null) {
            d.add(asdasd);
        }
    });
    return stocks;
```

**client::getInformation** is a blocking network call returning a List, all the **clientb.*** are doing is something like:

```
 return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> blockingNetworkCall(params, symbols)
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, value -> new Data(value.getValue(), TimePeriod.M1, TimePeriod.Y1))));
```

The original code looked something like this:

```
 List<String> symbols = client.block().get();
    Future<Map<String, Data>> smth = client.block2(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> ivM6MResultsFuture = clientB.getIvdataM6M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> ivM12MResultsFuture = clientB.getIvdataM12M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> iv2M6MResultsFuture = clientB.getIvdata2M6M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> iv2M12MResultsFuture = clientB.getIvdata2M12M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> iv2M24MResultsFuture = clientB.getIvdata2M24M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> hvM6MResultsFuture = clientB.getHvdataM6M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> hvM12MResultsFuture = clientB.getHvdataM12M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> hv2M6MResultsFuture = clientB.getHvdata2M6M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> hv2M12MResultsFuture = clientB.getHvdata2M12M(symbols);
    Future<Map<String, Double>> hv2M24MResultsFuture = clientB.getHvdata2M24M(symbols);
    Map<String, Data> doughResults = smth.get();
    Map<String, Double> ivM6MResults = ivM6MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> ivM12MResults = ivM12MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> iv2M6MResults = iv2M6MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> iv2M12MResults = iv2M12MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> iv2M24MResults = iv2M24MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> hvM6MResults = hvM6MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> hvM12MResults = hvM12MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> hv2M6MResults = hv2M6MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> hv2M12MResults = hv2M12MResultsFuture.get();
    Map<String, Double> hv2M24MResults = hv2M24MResultsFuture.get();
```

with a big for loop to map all the futures together and aggregate a result. Hopefully it's clear from the code what its doing, but essentially:

1. I make one network call that gets a list
2. Based on this list I call an internal service that generates some objects
3. Based on the first list I spawn a bunch of tasks to fetch various data
4. I populate the objects generated in 2 with the items in 3 - essentially 2 and 3 can run concurrently since they are not dependent.

Two main problems:

1. Do you see any problems with my `CompletableFuture` usage, and any room to improve the implementation based on the outlined criteria? Currently it's about 2x slower than regular blocking `.get()` old `Futures`, that is given as reference.
2. I am a little bit annoyed by the way joining is done, by having to call `.allOf()` with a void result, is there a better way to do that in the API that I am missing?

As a sidenote, I realize I'm doing a bit more work in the Java 8 variant with a bunch of streams and mapping happening, but the time difference is from 22sec in the old to 45secs in the new, and total items is about 200, so the majority is actually spent in networking and waiting and not the stream operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> smths = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(client::getSmth);
CompletableFuture<List<Data>> smths2 = smths.thenApply(client::getInformation)
        .thenApplyAsync((list) -> list.stream().map(obj -> mapper.map(obj, Data.class))
        .collect(toList()));
```

Since `smths` is only used in the immediate line, you can consider combining both together:

```
CompletableFuture<List<Data>> smths2 = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(client::getSmth).thenApply(client::getInformation)
        .thenApplyAsync(list -> list.stream().map(v -> mapper.map(v, Data.class))
        .collect(toList()));
```

On the same note, further down you are processing your `smths2` by the following:

```
List<Data> data = smths2.join();
// Map something...
data.forEach((d) -> {
    Set<AnotherData> asdasd = volPercent.get(d.getSymbol());
    if (asdasd != null) {
        d.add(asdasd);
    }
});
```

That can probably be done in a more functional way:

```
// Map something...
List<Data> data = smths2.join();
data.forEach(v -> Optional.ofNullable(volPercent.get(v.getSymbol()))
    .ifPresent(/* add this to v? */));
```

Your code actually wouldn't work as a `List<Data>` can't `add()` a `Set<AnotherData>`, possibly only an `addAll()` if `Data` is the parent class of `AnotherData`. Please *review* this part.

```
CompletableFuture
        .allOf(waitGroup.toArray(new CompletableFuture[waitGroup.size()]));
```

<s>The *return value* from the above doesn't seem to be used at all, copy-and-paste error?</s> Looks like this is [probably OK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30857778/2754160).

I'll like to review the chunk that is `waitGroup.add(...)`, but since it isn't clear what `notablesFuture` is, and unless one assumes it's the equivalent of doing a `List<String> symbols = client.block().get()` based on your original code... oh.

Now, it looks like `notablesFuture` is actually `smths`, and that changes the answer significantly...

### Take #2

First, you probably can use better method names than just `getIvPercentileM12M`, `getHvPercentile2M24M` etc. Second, instead of manually creating the `List` of `CompletableFuture`s, you can probably `Stream` it too using a small helper method to use method references in-place:

```
private static <T, U> Function<T, U> ref(Function<T, U> ref) {
    return ref;
}

private static Map<String, Set<Double>> getMap(Client client,
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> notablesFuture) {
    return Stream.of(
            ref(client::getIvPercentileM12M),
            ref(client::getIvPercentileM6M),
            ref(client::getIvPercentile2M6M),
            ref(client::getIvPercentile2M12M),
            ref(client::getIvPercentile2M24M),
            ref(client::getHvPercentileM6M),
            ref(client::getHvPercentile2M6M),
            ref(client::getHvPercentileM12M),
            ref(client::getHvPercentile2M12M),
            ref(client::getHvPercentile2M24M))
        .map(notablesFuture::thenComposeAsync).map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
}
```

Your code in your current method then becomes:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> notablesFuture = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(client::getSmth);
Map<String, Set<Double>> volPercent = getMap(clientb, notablesFuture);
List<Data> data = notablesFuture.thenApply(
            client::getInformation).thenApplyAsync(
            list -> list.stream().map(v -> mapper.map(v, Data.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())).join();
// use volPercent and data
```

Alternatively, you can consider making use of the `CompletableFuture` semantics completely (pun unintended):

```
// modify getMap's return value as such:
private static CompletableFuture<Map<String, Set<Double>>> getMap(Client client,
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> notablesFuture) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Stream.of(
            ref(client::getIvPercentileM12M),
            /* remaining method references... */)
        .map(notablesFuture::thenComposeAsync).map(CompletableFuture::join)
        /* remaining flatMap() and collect() steps... */ );
}
```

And the code in your current method can be then be modified into:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> notablesFuture = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(client::getSmth);
List<Double> result = getMap(clientb, notablesFuture).thenCombineAsync(
            notablesFuture.thenApply(client::getInformation).thenApplyAsync(
                list -> list.stream().map(v -> mapper.map(v, Data.class))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())), lookup()).join();
```

The `lookup()` method processes your `Map` and `List` results together in the solution you require, and since as mentioned above about not being able to `add()` a `Set<A>` to a `List<B>`, this will have to be open-ended... With that said, here's a sample implementation for reference:

```
private static BiFunction<Map<String, Set<Double>>, List<Data>, List<Double>> lookup() {
    return (map, list) -> list.stream().map(v -> map.get(v.getSymbol()))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: That was a pretty good explanation. To clarify this `CompletableFuture
        .allOf(waitGroup.toArray(new CompletableFuture[waitGroup.size()]));` was done to make sure everything in the waitgroup is completed before we proceed further. IE block until the previous pipeline completes. It's quite ugly so if you can suggest a more idiomatic way of doing it that would be great.

Comment: @Feras I believe you also need to call on the `CompletableFuture` returned by `allOf(...)` for it to work, e.g. a `join()`, at least that's what I gather from the tutorials online and my own little experimentation. I'm also not sure if you came across the same article, but [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html) is suggesting something similar to what you have (search for its `sequence()` implementation), so I suppose you are not that far off. :)

Comment: Turns out [I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30857778/2754160) in my understanding of `allOf(...)`, wells looks like I learned something new too.